# Return value must be of type Laravel 10

Tags: laravel

I am working on a Laravel 10 project and trying to create a controller that displays records. However, I have run into a problem while attempting to do so :

```
App\Http\Controllers\StudentController::index(): Return value must be of type Illuminate\Http\Response, Illuminate\View\View returned
```

I have attached below what I have tried so far:

**Student Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Models\Student;

class StudentController extends Controller
{

    public function index(): Response
    {
        $students = Student::all();
        return view ('students.index')->with('students', $students);
    }
```

If I remove the `Response` class, the code works, but I need to implement the Laravel 10 standard. I am unsure how to solve this issue. Can you please provide a solution?

**Routes**

```
Route::resource("/student", StudentController::class);
```

Answer (score 4):

Laravel utilized all of the type-hinting features available in PHP at the time. However, many new features have been added to PHP in the subsequent years, including additional primitive type-hints, return types, and union types.

[Release notes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/releases#types).

If you are using `view` function, you need to use the `Illuminate\View\View` class for type-hinting.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Models\Student;

class StudentController extends Controller
{
    public function index(): View
    {
        $students = Student::all();

        return view('students.index')
            ->with('students', $students);
    }
}
```